# How to close socket asynchronously

Tags: c++, boost-asio

This is my scenario. Several async writes are requested on a socket from a single thread. The same thread calls `io_service::run`. So I assume all completion handlers are executed in the same order as the corresponding async writes were initiated. Is it OK to shutdown and close the socket in the last completion handler?

Edit: I am using TCP protocol.

Comment: It's not even safe to call multiply async writes for single socket, at least in Boost.Asio. Only async read & write can be activated for a single socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to invoke `async_write()` from within the completion handler of the first `async_write()`. Pseudo code is below

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( ios );

void
handler2()
{
    socket.shutdown( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both );
    socket.close();
}

void
handler1()
{
    async_write( socket, boost::bind(&handler2) );
}

int
main()
{
    async_write( socket, boost::bind(&handler1) );
}
```

Note that the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) explicitly states a single outstanding operation can be in-flight:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
>   stream's `async_write_some` function, and is known as a composed
>   operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other
>   write operations (such as `async_write`, the stream's `async_write_some`
>   function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until
>   this operation completes.

Which is why invoking multiple `async_write()` operations on a single socket is a bad idea. Alternatively, use a [scatter operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html) to send both buffers in one `async_write()`.

Comment: Since you pointed out a flaw in my answer, I have deleted it. It's now only required that you add the bit about TCP vs UDP here, and your answer will be both correct and complete. +1 anyway.

Comment: And why use `bind` in this case?

Comment: @Yam the question is specific to TCP sockets. I used `boost::bind()` in my pseudo code because most completion handlers in the [asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) use a very similar technique.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a TCP socket (because UDP protocol is connectionless).

If you do something like this:

```
start_async_write(first)
start_async_write(second) -> close socket on complete
io_service.run()
```

everything will be OK, your writes will be serialized, `run()` method will return after `close` method of the socket will be called by the completion handler.

Comment: Apparently this is incorrect, by boost::asio's documentation.

Comment: `async_write()` is asynchronous like its name implies, you cannot invoke a second operation until the first completes and achieve deterministic behavior.

Comment: Why not? On windows async_write just call WriteFile under the hood. Second write will be pending until first completes. Completion handlers will be queued in FIFO order on the completion port. If you create to many outstanding writes, you get out of memory exception.

Comment: There are two problems with this.  Firstly, `async_write` does not necessarily call `WriteFile` once -- it might call it multiple times with some subset of the data to be written each time.  Secondly, while the completions are indeed scheduled FIFO through the completion port, the actual writes are not -- they can indeed be sent concurrently.  In practice both these things mean that for small writes it probably works most of the time, but it's a race condition lurking to arbitrarily interleave some of the data in longer writes or under system load; which is likely to ruin your day.